# remote connection to mysql

Tags: windows-7, mysql, remote-access, c#

have two machine PC#1 with db mysql and appache and PC#2 with a c# form try to connect to this db

here is my connection string used in PC#2: `SERVER=My_public_ip;PORT=3306;DATABASE = my_test; UID = root; PASSWORD = xxxx;"`

when i try to connect locally from PC#1 it work good:

```
SERVER=localhost;DATABASE = my_test; UID = root; PASSWORD = xxxx;"
```

i did make my root user remote enabled like that:

`GRANT ALL ON *.* to '%'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

and all i get is an Event viewer: `unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL host`

now i think it has nothing to do with firewall aftr turn them off on both pc and i still get the same error message, but i can't figure it out

Comment: Shut the firewall down and check if it works. If so, check out what port you're using and allow it.

Comment: same result, i did turn off firewall on both pc and i get the same error

Comment: It's not your firewall then.

Comment: it's good to know that

Comment: You have to configure mysql to allow remote connections.  Have you done this?

Comment: I did grant privileges but still can't connect, is that count

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question, I can suppose that PC#1 and PC#2 are not in the same LAN (public ip)

> SERVER=My_public_ip;PORT=3306

If this statement is correct, you have to port forward the port 3306 from your router to your PC#1's local ip.

[Here it is a good site](http://portforward.com/help/portforwarding.htm) that tell you what you have to do.

If your PC#1 and PC#2 are in the same LAN, then you have to change your "public_ip" with your "PC#1's local_ip".

Comment: so i need to find my router's ip then right?

Comment: you need your router's ip to setting up the port to forward and then your PC#1 local's ip. You can find all the information in the site from the answer. [Here is an example for the router NETGEAR DG834 and MySQL Server port](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/Netgear/DG834/MySQL_Server.htm)